# How can I find files recently downloaded from the Internet?

Tags: macos, data-transfer, web-browser

I sometimes struggle to find the files I downloaded from the Internet. They don't show up in "Recent files" in Finder, and if I'm not aware of the name they are also difficult to find in the Downloads folder.

How can I make this easier?

PS: I'm using Chrome (in case this is relevant)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- For some browsers (e.g. Safari, Firefox), you can access your recently downloaded files directly from the Download icon within the browser.

  [image: Recent downloads in Safari]

  [image: Recent downloads in Firefox]
- Safari, Firefox, Chrome allow to access recent downloads with a keyboard shortcut: Safari <kbd>Opt-Cmd-L</kbd>, Firefox <kbd>Cmd-J</kbd>, Chrome <kbd>Shift-Cmd-J</kbd>
- If you put your Downloads folder into the Dock (which it is, by default), you can just click on it to see the most recent additions/downloads
- You can also sort your Downloads folder by date added